# Add method with parameters to javascript object

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas, prototype-programming

I am currently in process of porting one of my java applet games to javascript+html5. I have never done object oriented javascript before and this prototype based OO stuff is confusing me a lot.

I tried to do a straightforward port from java but am having trouble doing two things:

1) How do I run a function inside a constructor?
2) How do I add a method that has a parameter?

Heres some example code:

```
function User()
{
    setupStats();// I wanted to put some of the variable initializations into
    // a separate function for code modularity reasons.

    this.name='bob';

    //However that doesn't seem to work
    alert(this.gold); // gets Undefined

    alert(this.name); // gets bob. Phew at least this works

    //I also want to add a method with a parameter in it:
    this.draw=function(ctx){drawUser(ctx);};
}

function setupStats()
{
    this.gold=2;
    this.exp=3;
    this.blah='blah';
    this.that='something else';
    this.superultraomg='insert some computation';
}

function drawUser(ctx)
{
    ctx.drawImage(blah,blah,blah);
    alert(ctx); // Also gets undefined. Uh oh...

    alert(this.name); //Undefined? WHAT IS THIS I DONT EVEN...
}
```

Please help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't too far off.  The trouble is mostly your use of the 'this' keyword.

You want something more like:

```
    var user = {};

    var user.setupStats = function ()
    {
        this.gold=2;
        this.exp=3;
        this.blah='blah';
        this.that='something else';
        this.superultraomg='insert some computation';
    };

    var user.init = function ()
    {
         this.name='bob';

         //Setup the stats
         this.setupStats();

         //However that doesn't seem to work
         alert(this.gold); // gets Undefined

         alert(this.name); // gets bob. Phew at least this works

         //I also want to add a method with a parameter in it:
         this.draw=function(ctx){drawUser(ctx);};
     };
```

You would continue this approach and execute calls against it by doing things like

```
user.init();
```

which would automatically chain your function references together.

Comment: Have you tested this?  Looks like a number of syntax errors to me.

Comment: Nope.  I was just trying to give him a little bit of an idea about function prototyping and how the scoping of the 'this' keyword can be affected.  Feel free to recommend edits to make the code above more copy/paste friendly.

Comment: I like this way of adding methods the most (simply because it makes my porting job a lot easier since it is most reminiscent of java's class based OO). However, your user.init = function() should be user.prototype.init = function(). Answer accepted :) Can someone with edit privileges fix the syntax errors though?

Answer (score 4):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sj4cN/)

We are using prototype, to share the defaults in `setupStats` with all `Users`. We are using [**call**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass a context, being the `User` object, and a `parameter`;

```
function User()
{
    setupStats();// I wanted to put some of the variable initializations into
    // a separate function for code modularity reasons.

    this.name='bob';

    //However that doesn't seem to work
    alert(this.gold); // gets Undefined

    alert(this.name); // gets bob. Phew at least this works

    //I also want to add a method with a parameter in it:
    this.draw= function(ctx){ drawUser.call(this, ctx); };
}

function setupStats()
{
    this.gold=2;
    this.exp=3;
    this.blah='blah';
    this.that='something else';
    this.superultraomg='insert some computation';
}

User.prototype = new setupStats();

new User().draw('pinky');

function drawUser(ctx)
{
    //ctx.drawImage(blah,blah,blah);
    alert(ctx); // Also gets undefined. Uh oh...

    alert(this.name); //Undefined? WHAT IS THIS I DONT EVEN...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading [JavaScript: The World's Most Misunderstood Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/javascript.html) by Douglas Crockford.  He explains clearly how classes, private members, public members, inheritance, etc. are done in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider encasing these methods in class scope, if there is still method ambiguity you can use dot notation to resolve the namespace ambiguity.  this.name works because it is defined in the same function, however other functions do not know that they are intended to exist in the same scope, thus they return undefined.

ctx is not defined in drawUser() because the parameters are declared incorrectly.  Javascrpit params should be delared as (NB they do not take the var keyword):

```
function methodName( aParam : aParamType, bParam : bParamType) {}
```

classes are declared using the class keyword [optional, omit square brackets]

```
[private public static] class ClassName [extends ParentClass] { /*methods here*/ }
```

hope this helps.